# Selecting a random option from a dropdown list

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to select a random option from a dropdown list. My understanding is that I need to count the number of available options, then select a random index between 0 and the number of available options.

So far I have this -

```
public static void selectRandomIndexDropdown(this IWebDriver driver, By elementName)
{
    var element = driver.FindElement(elementName);
    element.selectRandomIndexDropdown();
}

public static void selectRandomIndexDropdown(this IWebElement element)
{
    if (element == null || element.TagName.ToLower() != "select")
        return;

    int indexCount = element.FindElements(By.TagName("option")).Count();
    new SelectElement(element).SelectByIndex(Rnd.Next(0, indexCount));
}
```

And trying to call it -

```
driver.selectRandomIndexDropdown(By.XPath("//*[@id='ASPxGridViewDeskFees_DXEFL_DXEditor1_I']"));
```

This doesn't seem to work. No errors displayed or exceptions thrown, looks as though the code executes but just does not click on an option within the list. Any ideas?

Comment: Expand on - "doesn't seem to work" please.

Comment: Have added a little more detail, basically the code executes but no option is selected. No errors or exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 2):

*I'm using Java, but I'm sure the C# answer would be similar*

I generally use a method to give me the current list of options available:

```
public static List<WebElement> getOptions(WebElement selectField) {
    Select dropdown = new Select(selectField);
    return dropdown.getOptions();
}
```

From there, you select a random number between 0 and .size() to get a value to pass to the selection method:

```
public static void selectOptionByIndex(WebElement selectField, int index) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(selectField));
    Select dropdown = new Select(selectField);
    dropdown.selectByIndex(index);
}
```

Comment: Where do you select the random number ? xD

Answer (score 0):

Or simple generate randum X nuber from 2, to the number of options and find element like this:

```
string myxpath = "//*[@id='select_id']/option[" + X + "]";
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(myxpath));
```